# Unable to change my ip address

Tags: windows-7, ip

I can't change my ip address. When I right click local area connection -> properties, the properties for Internet Protocol Version 4 is greyed out. could anyone help me fix this? thanks a lot.

Or could anyone show me how to change ip address via command line?

Comment: Is your PC administrated by someone else? You might lack permissions for changing these settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your IP address via command line, use the following command:

> `netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1`

- `192.168.0.100` is your IP address
- `255.255.255.0` is your netmask
- `192.168.0.1` is your gateway

To also change your DNS server, use the following command:

> `netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.1`

- `192.168.0.1` is the IP address of your DNS server

These commands have to be used from an elevated command prompt (start as Administrator).

However, if you lack the permissions to change the settings via the GUI, these commands also might not work.